# Finish some animations of UIViewPropertyAnimator earlier

Tags: swift, animation, duration, uiviewpropertyanimator

I search for a way to add some animations to an `UIViewPropertyAnimator` which finishing earlier then others.
`UIViewPropertyAnimator` have for example a method where you can add animations with a delay

`animator.addAnimations(animation: (()-> Void), delayFactor: CGFloat)`

so the animation starts at 50% of the duration at a `delayFactor` of `0.5`.

I search for something like

`animator.addAnimations(animation: (()->Void), realtiveDuration: CGFloat)`

so the animation ends after 50% of the duration at a `relativeDuration`of `0.5`.

After some research I found a solution by using

```
animator.addAnimations {
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, animations: {
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.3) {
            view.alpha = 0.0
        }
    })
}
```

to archive this behavior.
Problem is, I want also use `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` to scrub through the animation.
Sadly this is not working with that `animateKeyframes` methods.

Have somebody another solution to archive this behavior?